# регулярное выражение для добавления префиксов в классы верстки

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, visual-studio-code

Всем привет! 
Необходимо в текстовом редакторе vscode с помощью регулярных выражений преобразовать строку вида: 
`class="dab alfa beta gamma-new delta"`  
в строку: 
`class="pre-dab pre-alfa pre-beta pre-gamma-new pre-delta"`

Сам смог добиться только таких результатов: 
`class="([^\s]+)(( [^\s]*)*)"` 
заменяю строкой: 
`class="pre-$1 pre-$2"` 
Но результат не тот.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

Найти:    `(?<=class="[^"]*?)[^\s"]+(?=[^"]*")`
Заменить: `pre-$0`

**Подробности**

- `(?<=class="[^"]*?)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, требующий наличия подстроки `class="`, потом 0 и более символов, отличных от `"`, как можно меньше, сразу перед текущей позицией в строке
- `[^\s"]+` - один и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов и двойной кавычки
- `(?=[^"]*")` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, требующий наличия 0 и более символов, отличных от `"`, а затем `"` сразу после текущей позиции в строке.

`$0` – обратная ссылка на целый текст совпадения.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

```
class="pre-dab pre-alfa pre-beta pre-gamma-new pre-delta"
```